# Key bind for arrow keys in sublime

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, sublimetext3, key-bindings, alt-key

I use sublime text editor for writing code, and I want to set up a key binding for arrow keys, so I don't need to move my right hand frequently. To do so, I added code in sublime-keymap:

```
[
{ "keys": ["alt+j"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false} },
    { "keys": ["alt+l"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true} },
    { "keys": ["alt+i"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward":false} },
    { "keys": ["alt+k"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true} },
]
```

But, `alt+j` and `alt+k` are not working. Please help.
I tried to key bind in `VS code` too, the same problem occurs.
I am using OS Windows 10; the hotkeys defined by windows is creating this issue?

Comment: Works perfectly for me, except I have removed ` chars (line 2 and line 5)

Comment: Works fine for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

For **vscode** only, the commands are a little different (in your keybindings.json):

```
{
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "left",
        "by": "character"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "alt+l",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "right",
        "by": "character"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
    {
    "key": "alt+i",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "up",
        "by": "line"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
    {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "down",
        "by": "line"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

This is for moving the cursor within an editor.  If you wanted arrow key-like functionality in a list - like the Explorer files - you would have to add some more keybindings with different commands.  But it looks like you just want within a text editor.